# Is there an escape Latex characters option in Mendeley Reference Manager?

Tags: bibliographies, citing, overleaf, mendeley

Since Mendeley Desktop is no longer available, I have installed Mendeley Reference Manager. However, it seems that the new software does not have a feature to escape special LaTeX characters.

When I export my entire library as a .bib file to upload it to Overleaf, the citations do not appear correctly when I compile the document. Upon examining the uploaded .bib file, I noticed numerous warnings indicating the presence of % or _ characters. Is there an option in Mendeley Reference Manager to properly escape these characters, as was possible in the previous Mendeley Desktop version?

I've put a \ character before some special characters, but I'd expect to find a suitable solution as my library is changing and growing.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a compilable TeX code and two bib entries ...